# Is there an easy way to get rid of miniflags when copying table data from Wikipedia into Excel?

Tags: excel

Is there an easy way to get rid of the mini flags when copying table data from Wikipedia and pasting it into Microsoft Excel?

Btw there's no answer to the question on any other sites when I googled it. If there is please share the link and I will delete this question.

[image: mini flags when copying table data from wikipedia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pasting into Excel instead of pasting normally (using ctrl + v), go to the Home tab and under Clipboard > Paste, select *match destination formatting*. It will not copy over the flags.